# how integrate an existing vuejs app created with vue-cli into a laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I've a vuejs app builded with the latest vue-cli, the vuejs app runs ok with the development server and communicates with the laravel app, but now I'd prefer that laravel handle this static files...if I build the js files with `yarn run build` this generates me several files, I could add thems to my laravel homepage but I'm afraid that if in the future I make some change and build these files again, I could get different file names...

what is the best approach for this???...I've found several articles integrating vuejs and laravel but all these are using the vuejs tool incorporated with laravel

thanks so much guys

Comment: Keep your back end / API separate from your client application. Think about it logically, your (web based) client application makes requests to your API in order to generate content for the user. What happens one day if you wanted to say, make a mobile or desktop client application? Would you rewrite everything for that or simply adjust your client application code to accommodate for it?

Comment: thanks @CraigvanTonder, the main problem here is running nodejs and php seems a bit overengineered for a simple app, I think would be better for this app run the static content with php/laravel...

I've routes,npm modules installed and seems a bit complicate integrate them in the laravel app